# How to check if .mov format is supported in video tag of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to embed .mov file into browser. I want to display the video only if it is supported in the browser or else I just want to display an image of the video. I am looking for particular type .mov not any other formats like mp4,ogg etc.

I wanted to use only video tag not any other third party plugins.

I tried below code to check if .mov is supported but it doesn't work. Is there any way to check if the video is supported in browser in javascript/jquery.

```
 var v = document.createElement("video");
 if(v.canPlayType && v.canPlayType('video/mov').replace(/no/,'')){
     console.log('Can play video');
 } else {
     console.log('Cannot play video');
 }
```

Comment: The correct MIME type for `.MOV` files is `video/quicktime`, not `video/mov`.

Comment: I have tried video/quicktime in the code, but it doesn't work. Can you please add any working snippet of code if you have any.

Comment: I have tried it in chrome, it is playing my .mov file but displays message saying 'Cannot play video' for the above code snippet.